# How do I attach a Javascript event to the mobile Safari back button?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, dom-events

I need to show a confirm dialog box when the user clicks the back button in mobile Safari. I have a long application, and I want to alert users that their application has not been filled out/completed before they leave the page. I have everything set up for when the user clicks a link and tries to leave the page, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to attach an event to the browser's back button. `onbeforeunload` does not work in iOS. Any tips would be much appreciated.

NOTE: I realize alert boxes are the spawn of satan, but that's what I was told to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the `persisted` property of the `onpageshow` event. It is set to false on initial page load. When page is loaded from bfcache (user navigates back with back button) it is set to true.

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        alert("From back / forward cache.");
    }
};
```

For some reason jQuery does not have this property in the event. You can find it from original event though.

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
      alert("From back / forward cache.");
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In desktop browsers like Chrome you can intercept the leaving of a page and show a message. 
And you can't do anything, except for showing the message. The browser is doing the rest, for obvious reasons.
Dunno if this also works on iOS.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return 'do you really wanna do that?'
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JAAZ5/

Comment: I had it all set up using onbeforeunload, but unfortunately, it does not work in iOS.

Comment: iOS does not fire the onbeforeunload event.

Comment: Like I said, unno If it works on iOS, since I don't have an iOS device, I couldn't test it. At least I made a proposal :)

Answer (score -2):

Control over the back button has never been allowed in any browser. I suspect mobile Safari is no different.

Comment: history.pushstate and the popstate event allow for significant detection/modification of the back button in a wide variety of browsers; but how do they work in iOS?